# Best way to reduce tax burden of a signing bonus

Tags: united-states, job-offer, bonus

My friend has been given a job offer with a generous signing bonus under the label of housing and child-tuition support to help towards the burden of relocation.

The only problem is that the company notes that taxes will reduce the bonus by approximately 30%. They offer to break the bonus up into separate payments.

What is the best mechanism by which that person can reduce the tax burden of the bonus? I assume that splitting the payments up (even over several years) will not reduce the taxes significantly given the high tax bracket  that person is in.

Note: That person has not yet accepted the position and so issues like this are negotiable.

**Related: [How are bonuses taxed? Why is withheld amount not same as final amount?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46472/how-are-bonuses-taxed-why-is-withheld-amount-not-same-as-final-amount)**

Comment: Why is the linked question not answering your query?

Comment: The linked question is about the taxation structure of bonuses and the withholding. This is specifically about how to avoid such taxes.

Comment: Ask the company to [gross it up](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gross-up.asp)! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the payments does have one short time effect, the initial withholding may be lower.

Lets say the bonus is $20,000 and they make $60,000 a year. If the company treats it as a lump sum they may withhold 25% for federal taxes. This would mean that $5000 would be withheld right away. It would not matter if the friend was single, married, head of household or had many exemptions on their W-4. If the bonus was added to their monthly salary and appeared to the IRS as a regular monthly salary a bonus that large could cause even more withholding from [IRS circular E](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf):

```
Monthly
Status   Over       but not over    withhold              of excess over—
Single   $15,967    — $34,483..     $3,839.64 plus 33%           —$15,967
Married  $19,921    — $35,008..     $4,298.17 plus 33%           —$19,921
```

That would put your friend into the the 33% withholding rate for that month. If they are paid every two weeks they could be in the 39.6% bracket for that pay check.

If they split it into multiple payments it could bring the withholding for those months back down to 25%. Of course that does spread out the payments, so if they need the cash to pay for the move that is a consideration.

> with a generous signing bonus under the label of housing and
>   child-tuition support to help towards the burden of relocation.

If the friend meets the [time and distance test](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p521/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000203454) they may be able to claim some moving expenses. This will allow them to reduce their income.

> **Distance Test**
>
> Your move will meet the distance test if your new main job location is
>   at least 50 miles farther from your former home than your old main job
>   location was from your former home. For example, if your old main job
>   location was 3 miles from your former home, your new main job location
>   must be at least 53 miles from that former home. You can use Worksheet
>   1 to see if you meet this test.
>
> **Time Test for Employees**
>
> If you are an employee, you must work full time for at least 39 weeks
>   during the first 12 months after you arrive in the general area of
>   your new job location (39-week test). Full-time employment depends on
>   what is usual for your type of work in your area.
>
> For purposes of this test, the following four rules apply.
>
> - You count only your full-time work as an employee, not any work you do as a self-employed person.
> - You do not have to work for the same employer for all 39 weeks.
> - You do not have to work 39 weeks in a row.
> - You must work full time within the same general commuting area for all 39 weeks.

Once you pas those test you can claim expenses:

> **Deductible Moving Expenses**
>
> If you meet the requirements discussed earlier under Who Can Deduct
>   Moving Expenses, you can deduct the reasonable expenses of:
>
> - Moving your household goods and personal effects (including in-transit or foreign-move storage expenses), and
> - Traveling (including lodging but not meals) to your new home.
>
> You cannot deduct any expenses for meals.

Of coure this savings won't happen until that taxes are filed next spring.

Comment: IRS W2 withholdings are really re-calculated on a monthly basis? I don't know why that's so shocking... I guess I just expected a more accurate estimation of the annual income. Anyways, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

The ways you might try to shelter it would be the same as for salary or other income: Max out your 401(k) or IRA or equivalent, and your HSA if you have one, and consider tax-free  educational savings plans for your kids, and...

Getting paid more means getting taxed more. I find it easier to just ignore the pretax numbers entirely. My real salary is the post-tax amount; the difference was never mine in the first place. That doesn't mean I don't try to get some of it back when filing my taxes, but I budget my life based on what I know I'm keeping rather han on money I'll never see except on paper.

Two things are certain, and the one we're likely to beat first isn't taxes.